# jsPDF custom paper size

Tags: size, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF 1.4 to generate a document to use in a card printer, with a custom paper size.

First of all, I can't find jsPDF 1.4 docs, all I can find is [last's version docs](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html).

The current call that former programmer used is this:

```
var def = $.Deferred();
doc = new jsPDF("landscape", self.Constants.jsPDFunit.milimeters, "a5");
doc.fromHTML(fullHtml, 10, 10, {
            'width': 'auto'
        }, function (finish) {
            if (iframe)
                loadJsPDFToIframe(doc);
            else
                doc.output('save', 'auto-pdf.pdf');
            def.resolve(true);
        });
```

I would like to know:

1. What are those *10, 10* values? Margins maybe?
2. How can I force HTML DOM to extend to full page size or how can I make paper/canvas size to fix HTML size?